# PHP date/time function

Tags: php

I've an application,say the end user might be from any country but when he does some action,i want the date to be shown in a particular time zone.

I want insert this into DB so i'm doing this using date_default_timezone_set('');  with date()

Is this the right way or should i use gmdate() and add time zone.

Thanks

Comment: Of side note, realize that time in PHP is based on the webserver, not where the client is located.

Comment: @TimDearborn:So i can get the server time and add/subtract according to my time zone,will this work ?

Comment: Some of the time. Different settings for Daylight Savings Time as such could throw it off at various times of the year.  You would want to use `gmdate()` and then adjust for your timezone, as Jesse Bunch mentioned in his answer.

Comment: @TimDearborn:I know to use gmdate(),how to adjust to my time zone ?

Answer (score 1):

No, don't use `date_default_timezone_set()` for timezone conversions. This can have unintended side-effects.

Instead, use this:

```
$tz = new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles');

$date = new DateTime('Thu, 31 Mar 2011 02:05:59 GMT');
$date->setTimeZone($tz);
echo $date->format('l F j Y g:i:s A I')."\n";
```

Note, you're creating the DateTime object using UTC time and then applying the timezone. This way is much cleaner.

Comment: :Now when ever any one in the world uses my app,it always store date in my time zine,i mentioned,am i right.Can you see  Tim Dearborn comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you want GMT, I think you should use the right Timezone as `Europe/London`

```
  date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
```